# create XmlSerializer in MFC C++

Tags: c++, xml, xml-serialization

I want to implement in my MFC application project this logic, which written in C# looks like:

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(A_CLASS));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
XmlWriterSettings sett = new XmlWriterSettings();
sett.Indent = true;
sett.IndentChars = "\t";
using (XmlWriter sw = XmlWriter.Create(sb, sett))
{
    ser.Serialize(sw, A_CLASS_Instance);
}
```

How can I write this in C++?

Answer (score 1):

MFC will not really help you here, but as usual in C++ today, [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) is your friend :)

The [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/) library has `xml_oarchive` and `xml_iarchive`. For simple examples, have a look here: http://www.fnord.ca/articles/xml.html

However – do check out the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225283/best-xml-serialization-library-for-a-mfc-c-app) as well.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, MFC doesn't provide any classes for XML serialization. But there might be libraries out there.